# Getting the issue while initializing repository in vscode

Tags: git, gitlab, visual-studio-code

I want to initialize my repository in vscode but somehow the Initialize Repository button is disabled in my vscod. I cloned the project from gitlab. But not able to initialize git in vscode is there any solution for that? Here is the screenshot of that[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vf2ou.png)

Comment: use double backslah in git directory path

Answer (score 0):

If it was `clone`-ed from gitlab it is already a git repository. Meaning git is already tracking it. This is why you are not seeing a `Initialize Repository` button.

Try `ls` in your root directory to see that you already have a `.git` directory.

```sh
ls .git
```

Git uses this directory to keep a track of your changes and to save commit nodes.

Now that you know it is initilized, go ahead and make changes and commit them to git.

Comment: But I am not able to track my changes in vscode. If I made changes it shows me when I run git status command. But when I clicked on git icon from the vscode left sidebar it doesn't shows me my changes

Comment: What do you see i the side bar? If you see changes in the termial then probabily you've opened `vs code` in the wrong directory and it fails to find a `.git` file. Note: `git` command line CLI can look back a tree (meaning it can step up a directory tree to search for the `.git` directory

Comment: I have my project in my E:/my-project I opened my-project folder in vscode. I think path is also correct, which I opened in vscode

Comment: Please answer these: 1) Does the `git status` command show you a result with changes? 2) If so what is the location of the terminal when you used the `git` command?

Comment: 1) Yes git status command is showing me my changes

2) Location of my terminal - E:\my-project

Comment: One more thing I am getting this type of error in my vscode also
extension host terminated unexpectedly

Comment: If your terminal says `E:\my-project` but vscode can't see the git history its your vscode at falt. Try opening a diff local git repo and see if it still has issues. If so check if there are any errors at vscode side. Fix them

Comment: git diff also shows me diff, I think issue at vscode side need  to check about that

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and setting my directory as a "safe.directory" solved it.

```
git config --global --add safe.directory [path of the directory where you want to put your repository]
```